# If I were to type the output of `\showlists` into a TeX file, would I get the exact same thing as what I started with?

Tags: plain-tex

Suppose I create a TeX file, and right before closing, I run `\showlists`. Then, I look at my log file, and (roughly) copy and paste everything from `\showlists` into a new TeX file.

Will the two .dvi files outputted from these two things always be the same?

Comment: Definitely not. That output is a representation of the innards of TeX after it has digested some lists and transformed them into boxes. It has no relationship with whatever you can input.

Comment: No, almost none of `\showlists` output is tex syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. (but it may be near enough, depending on your real use case).

Firstly the actual syntax is quite different. From the answer posted to your last question:

```
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 8
\tenrm c
\tenrm c
\tenrm c
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
spacefactor 1000
```

the lines starting `#` would be a synax error, `\glue` would need to be (in this case) `\hskip` and have `pt` units added. `spacefactor` settings are automatic so don't really correspond to any input.....

However I suspect that your real question is, "does the output from `\showlists` have enough information to allow you to construct an equivalent document".

There the answer is that I think it probably has enough information to construct the body of the current page, although I know of no automated way to do that. It does not give information about previous pages (TeX has essentially discarded them from memory) and also it will not have the information about any page head or foot that will be added to the current page in the output routine.

But for a one page document with known page head and foot, then possibly the answer is yes.

Comment: What is a page head or foot?

Comment: @extremeaxe5 the part at the top of the page that is inserted by latex, not from the body, typically with page numbers or small versions of section titles etc, see for example the `fancyhdr` package. but a small 1-page article document would have a  page number 1 inserted at the bottom of the page which would not show in `\showlists` but that may not matter if your reconstructed document is also article class and also has a page number 1 automatically inserted at the same place.